# Do Visual Studio coded ui tests support dll injection?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, dll-injection

Various ui test automation frameworks seem to use some form of dll injection in order to allow the test code to inspect inspect (or even modify) properties of the application under test that would not be visible otherwise. This can help tests to interact with more complex non-standard UI controls.

Is this supported by Visual Studio coded ui tests?

Comment: It's unclear to me - you are asking whether you can test some properties of visual controls and to what extend? It depends on whether control shippers support so called MSAA. There are different levels of supporting. So actually it's not VS feature but control-shippers.

Comment: I'm not talking about MSAA. TestComplete and Ranorex both inject code into the application under test so that they can look at its internals. It's basically a workaround for when controls don't support MSAA